# Silex render form - ChoiceType

Tags: php, forms, twig, silex, selected

(and sorry for my English)

I am working on a Silex project and I start using the form.

Without form, i have something like this : 
[image: Image of choicesType]

And using the form I would like to have the same thing (**for the select**)

End with the form i have this :

[image: ImageAfterChoicesTypeForm]

As you can see the rendering is not great.

I would like to get a few things like:

```
<option value="1">Méthode</option>
 <option value="2">Marketing</option>
 <option value="3">Production</option>
```

At the code level, I have something very simple (
I start on the forms, be indulgent haha) : 
Controller :

```
public function add(Application $app, Request $request) {
        if (! $app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return new Response('Access Denied!', 403);
        }
        $repo = new DepartementRepository($app);
        $departements = $repo->getAllDepartements();

        $data = [];
        $erreurs = [];
        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data)
        ->add('nom',null,array('label' => 'Nom :'))
        ->add('prenom',null,array('label' => 'Prenom :'))
        ->add('departement_id',ChoiceType::class,array('choices' => $departements,'label' => 'Departement :'))
        ->add('ville',null,array('label' => 'Ville :'))
        ->add('salaire',null,array('label' => 'Salaire :'))
        ->add('date_embauche',null,array('label' => 'Date d\'embauche :'))
        ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $data = $form->getData();
        }
        return $app['twig']->render('employe/new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),'erreurs'=> $erreurs));
    }
```

if i dump my $departements variable, i have this :

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "2"
    "nom_dep" => "Marketing"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "3"
    "nom_dep" => "Méthode"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "1"
    "nom_dep" => "Production"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "4"
    "nom_dep" => "Recherche et developpement"
  ]
]
```

And my view :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
     <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Before I did that:

```
{% for departement in departements %}
           <option value="{{ departement.id }}"
           {% if donnees.departement_id is defined and departement.id == donnees.departement_id %}selected{% endif %}>
                   {{ departement.nom_dep }}
           </option>
{% endfor %}
```

But I do not know how to do this with the form.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChoiceType takes an array as parameter:

Array style (like your current repo)

```
 $departements = $repo->getAllDepartements();
 $departementChoices = [];
 foreach( $departements as $departement) {
   $departementChoices[$departement["id"]] = $departement["nom_dep"]
 }
```

Object style

```
 $departements = $repo->getAllDepartements();
 $departementChoices = [];
 foreach( $departements as $departement) {
   $departementChoices[$departement->getId()] = $departement->getLabel()
 }
```

Comment: It was  ``$departementChoices[$departement["id"]] = $departement["nom_dep"]``

  But it works ! Thanks a lot !